# Protractor doesn't send data for login keys,

Tags: protractor

I have an issue relating to sending keys to login  page, only the browser launched and nothing happens, how ever was able to  run the script previously with no issue.This might be due to  an upgrade on angular in the test server any  solution for it much appreciated? recently  had angualr 5 upgrade from a lower version

```
describe(' E2E1', function () {

afterEach(function () {
    browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
    browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
    browser.restart();
});

it('Scenario 1', function () {
    browser.get('some url');
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('#company-code')))
        .then(function () {
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('company-code')).sendKeys('cc');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('email@dmoain.com');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('sompepassword');
            browser.driver.findElement(by.id('signin')).click()
                .then(function () {
                    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
                    browser.wait(EC.urlContains('URL after login'), 100000).then(function () {
                        console.log('Successfully logged')
                    });
                });
        });
});
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post the code snippet? or provide more details about the problem.

Comment: @arpitjain2402 Thanks for reaching out here is the some sample of it I have modified the question

Comment: @arpitjain2402 Tried some edit for the code to get the  script working
but no  clue yet:

Comment: could you please provide some insights into the error message you get once you run the tests.

Comment: which ChromeDriver version do you have?

Comment: You probably need to update chromedriver to the correct version that is compatible with your version of Chrome.

Comment: @arpitjain2402 yah finally it worked, I have to modify the code  to set angular false to every specs so now it's work fine, thanks for help,@catch22  it's Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)